# How can I make SignInAsync working right here?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, httpcontext, claims

Can someone tell me how to fix that error?

> HttpContext does not contain a definition of SignInAsync.

In another project I made with tutorial it works right. Using package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<User>> LoginUser(LoginDto dto)
    {
        User loggedInUser = await _context.Users.Where(u => u.Email == dto.Email && u.PasswordHash == HashDtoPassword(dto.Password).PasswordHash).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (loggedInUser != null)
        {
            //create a claim
            var claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loggedInUser.Email);
            //create claimsIdentity
            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { claim }, "serverAuth");
            //create claimsPrincipal
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            //Sign In User
            //error down here 
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(loggedInUser);
    }
```

Comment: JFYI. `return await Task.FromResult(loggedInUser);` can be just `return loggedInUser;` (or even should be something like `return Ok(user);`) - your method is async.

Comment: Problem is with line " await HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal) " i want create token. Return works right

Comment: I understand where your problem is. That is why my comment has "JYI" and is not an answer.  _"Return works right"_ - I was not claiming that it is working wrong. It is just extra not needed code which is doing small but not needed work.

Comment: Are you using an instance method in a class which has a property called `HttpContext`? Based on the error message, it looks like you're trying to call a `static` method on the `HttpContext` type, rather than [the extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.signinasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on *an instance of* the `HttpContext` type.

Comment: Was the _"another project I made with tutorial"_ using .NET Framework?

Answer (score 1):

`SigninAsync` is an extension method of the class `HttpContext` in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` namespace.  Here is a working example based off a new Web API project.  You probably need to add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAsync()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync("scheme", new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal());
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```